# Need a explanation over mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this query and I don't understand what it's doing. How I can translate it into `SQL`?

```
db.videos.find({deleted: {$ne: true}}).count();
```

I think this query will count videos where deleted field value is false.

Comment: Your thoughts are correct. That is indeed what the query will match. Knowing this, I don't feel that you are really asking a mongo question but rather an SQL question. As you can now see, the query you are asking for is pretty straight forward - what exactly do you need assistance with?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to translate it to SQL, Mongo is a noSQL database server.

Please explain your scenario better because something is fishy here.
Anyway, this is the translation to SQL (again, doesnt make any sense).

```
Select count(*) from videos where deleted <> 'true'
```